# Segmentation fault when jumping to goto over VLA array

Tags: c++, gcc, variable-length-array

The following example demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
        unsigned int remaining=1;

        goto loop;

        while(remaining) {
                unsigned char tmp[remaining];
                printf("&tmp: %p\n",tmp);
loop:
                remaining = 512;//or something else;
        }
}
```

Initially, the initialization of "remaining" variable was a bit long and I used `goto` to initialize it on one line. However, now this example gives segmentation fault on the `printf` line.

It looks like the array is not initialized properly.

Even gdb cannot print the tmp array's address:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005b8 in main () at test.cpp:11
11          printf("&tmp: %p\n",tmp);
(gdb) p tmp
$1 = 0xfffffffffffffe00 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffffffffe00>
```

My gcc version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

compiling with:

```
g++ -o testc test.cpp
```

If I remove the goto, or replace the variadic array with a fixed array, the segmentation fault is gone.
What is happening actually?

Is this a gcc bug? If the combination of `goto` and variadic arrays is not allowed, there should be a warning?

Comment: Compile your example with recent clang or gcc 4.9.* and they will not allow your code to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable length arrays(*VLA*) are a C99 feature that gcc supports as [an extension in C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and in C99 a jump across a VLA declaration is undefined behavior, from the draft C99 standard section `6.8.6.1` *The goto statement*:

> A goto statement shall not jump from outside the scope of an identifier having
>   a variably modified type to inside the scope of that identifier.

`clang` and `gcc 4.9` actually makes this an error and says:

```
error: goto into protected scope
    goto loop;
    ^

note: jump bypasses initialization of variable length array
            unsigned char tmp[remaining];
                          ^
```

See the [gcc bug report:  Jumps into VLA or VM scope not rejected for C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21113).

The rules for jumping past a declaration of an automatic variable in C++ is covered in section `6.7` *[stmt.dcl]* which says:

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that
>   bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps87 from
>   a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in
>   scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the
>   variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of
>   these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared
>   without an initializer (8.5). [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     // ...
>     goto lx; // ill-formed: jump into scope of a
> ly:
>     X a = 1;
>     // ...
> lx:
>     goto ly; // OK, jump implies destructor
>              // call for a followed by construction
>             // again immediately following label ly
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: A good start, but this doesn't prove that GCC's extension considers it undefined behaviour. Unless it's documented somewhere that the C++ VLA extension behaves just as it would in C99. Of course, in reality, C++ itself prohibits this jump, so I'd call it a GCC bug that it lets you do that (but then breaks) when it's a VLA declaration you're jumping over.

Comment: gcc 4.9.* also produces a similar error. It's just probably earlier gcc that doesn't capture it.

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu I initially tested with `4.8` but you are correct `4.9` does as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit looks like it was fixed in `gcc 4.9`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit was looking and I found it and updated

Comment: That's it. Great stuff! +1